# CS1061: 'IEnumerable<>' does not contain a definition for '' and no extension method '' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, api

I'm new to .net MVC Please help me to solve my problem.

I'm getting this error:
CS1061: 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found.

here is my controller 
     public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return Index();
        }

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Person model)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:23793");

        client.PostAsJsonAsync<Person>("api/person", model)
            .ContinueWith((postTask) => postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode());

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

And here my view

```
           @model IEnumerable<PersonDemoMVC.Models.Person>

        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Create";
        }

        <h2>Create</h2>


        @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <h4>Person</h4>
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }

        <div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>

        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Should this view display a single person or multiple people?

Answer (score 5):

Your Create view is strongly typed to a collection of `Person` entity(`IEnumerable<Person>`) and in your view you are executing code like `Model.Name` (*model=>model.Name* in Html helper methods). Here Model is a `IEnumerable<Person>` and IEnumerable does not have a `Name` property !.

Instead of using a collection, Use a single instance of Person as your model in your create view.

```
@model PersonDemoMVC.Models.Person
<h2>Create</h2>
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Name)
   <!-- Your existing form elements -->
   <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: I changed the model to @model PersonDemoMVC.Models.Person.
And it through this error :
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PersonDemoMVC.Models.Person]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'PersonDemoMVC.Models.Person'.

Comment: In your GET action, Are you passing a collection ? You should pass a single instance of `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

You defined your model as `IEnumerable<PersonDemoMVC.Models.Person>`.
Later on you try to call property Name on model
Line: `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })`

**You should:**

1. Change model to sth like: PersonDemoMVC.Models.Person

**OR**

2. Loop through the model in order to recieve single Person object instance.

Comment: I changed the model to @model PersonDemoMVC.Models.Person. And it through this error : The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PersonDemoMVC.Models.Person]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'PersonDemoMVC.Models.Person'.

Answer (score 0):

Since the model you are using is a enumerable therefore go for foreach or for loop

```
@model IEnumerable<PersonDemoMVC.Models.Person>

        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Create";
        }

        <h2>Create</h2>


        @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <h4>Person</h4>
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
     @foreach(var item in model)
       {
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(i => item.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => item.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => item.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(i => item.Age, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => item.Age, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => item.Age, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       }
        }

        <div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>

        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the First Method as below

@Html.LabelFor(**model => model.First().Name**, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).